# Passing a table's just one value to another table in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I took these variables from user

```
@KullaniciAdi nvarchar(30),
@KullaniciSoyadi nvarchar(30),
@KullaniciMailAdresi nvarchar(max),
@KullaniciTelNo tinyint,
@KullaniciSehir nvarchar(30)
```

but my table wants me to get `KullaniciSehirID` from another `Sehir` table.

So I declared

```
declare @KullaniciSehirID int
```

this variable and I want to pass this

```
Select Sehir.SehirID 
FROM Sehir 
WHERE Sehir.SehirAdi = @KullaniciSehir
```

Selection returns to my variable, but I couldn't do it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select @KullaniciSehirID = SehirID FROM Sehir WHERE Sehir.SehirAdi=@KullaniciSehir
```

@KullaniciSehirID will have the correct value in it, you can use that in the rest of your query

Comment: Yes, that was what I've looking for. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @UğurcanŞengit Great, if someones answers solves your problem mark it as the answer (green tick to the left). Helps the site tick along :)